# Is there some other way to perform fractional distillation without using Vigreux Column?

Tags: purification, distillation

So recently I was performing an esterification reaction of oils like peanut oil or any neutral oil where I got some products which are only possible to filter using fractional distillation. I already have a setup for simple distillation and I even have condensers like Liebig, Allihn and Graham. Still, unfortunately, prior to this reaction I haven't purchased a Vigreux column and since the cost of the Vigreux column is a bit out of budget. Is there any safe alternative for doing fractional distillation without the Vigreux column or is it worth purchasing Vigreux column for fractional distillation?

Comment: "which are only possible to filter using fractional distillation" is a contradiction.  Either you filter, to separate solids from liquids, or you distill, which is a separation of liquids by different boiling points. Second, too little information about the product (perhaps it solidifies over time/can crystallize out) or scale (if the reaction is large enough, one may pack a column with beads of glass, though the dead volume is *much* larger than the one of a Vigreux column). Third *fractional* in *fractional* distillation is about the receiver, not the column on top of the round bottom flask.

Comment: So *fractional* is more about how you proceed in gently heating the mixture to separate in first place.  Depending on scale, and difference of the boiling points of the liquids to separate *at a given pressure*, a distillation may be performed *well enough* without a column at all, too.